# How to Use a Non-unique Key in Terraform Resource Loop to Create Unique Resources

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I'd like to create every type of DNS record for a domain using a generic module, and so be able to call it with something like:

```
module "example_com_dns" {
  source = "[PATH_TO_MODULES]/modules/dns"

  domain  = "example.com"

  a_records = {
    "@"    = [SOME IP]
    "www"  = [SOME IP]
    "home" = [SOME IP]
  }

  txt_records = {
    "@"                    = "txt-foobar1"
    "@"                    = "txt-foobar2"
    "mail._domainkey.self" = "foobar"
  }

  mx_entries = {
     "10" = "mail.someprovider.com"
     "20" = "mail2.someprovider.com"
  }

  cname_records {
    "cname-foo" = "cname-bar
  }
}
```

I have something that works fine for A, CNAME , and MX records, but TXT has an edge case which I need to work around. My module has resource blocks for each type of record, which run through loops. I'll just paste the TXT one, but they're all the same:

```
resource "digitalocean_record" "this_txt_record" {
  for_each = var.txt_records

  domain = var.domain
  type   = "TXT"
  name   = each.key
  value  = each.value
}
```

This all works fine, *except* for the fact that since there are 2 records with "@" for their key, it results in only the last one being created (in my example above, this being "txt-foobar2"):

```sh
...

  # module.example_com.digitalocean_record.this_txt_record["@"] will be created
  + resource "digitalocean_record" "this_txt_record" {
      + domain = "example.com"
      + fqdn   = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + name   = "@"
      + ttl    = (known after apply)
      + type   = "TXT"
      + value  = "txt-foobar2"
    }
```

I'd like for it to create both "txt-foobar1" and "txt-foobar2", even given non-unique keys in the map.

Perhaps this is the wrong way and I just need to figure out a clever loop for for parsing this structure instead?:

```
  txt_records = [
    { "@" = "foo" },
    { "@" = "bar"},
    { "mail._domainkey.self" = "foobar"}
  ]
```

If so, I'm currently failing there too :)

Comment: In your proposed new structure, where would `"mail._domainkey.self" = "foobar"` be?

Comment: Oh in the same list, I just forgot to add it. I edited the example in the question now to include it.

Comment: Is `mail._domainkey.self"` a constant string, or it can take different value?

Comment: That one is always the same, but it's just an example. Most of the time you would have a unique record mapping for TXT (and for some other record types, I believe it's even mandatory), but for this one use-case where we need to set things like SPF records, we always use "@".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way to already given one is to use the following:

```
 variable "txt_records" {
  default = {
       "@" = ["foo", "bar"],
       "mail._domainkey.self" = ["foobar"]
       }
 }
```

Then you can flatten the `txt_records` using:

```
locals {

  txt_records_flat = merge([
      for key, values in var.txt_records:
        {for value in values: 
           "${key}-${value}" => {"record_name" = key, "record_value" = value}
        }
  ]...)
}
```

which results in `local.txt_records_flat` of:

```
{
  "@-bar" = {
    "record_name" = "@"
    "record_value" = "bar"
  }
  "@-foo" = {
    "record_name" = "@"
    "record_value" = "foo"
  }
  "mail._domainkey.self-foobar" = {
    "record_name" = "mail._domainkey.self"
    "record_value" = "foobar"
  }
}
```

Then you use it:

```
resource "digitalocean_record" "this_txt_record" {
  for_each = local.txt_records_flat

  domain = var.domain
  type   = "TXT"
  name   = each.value.record_name
  value  = each.value.record_value
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, and am opting for Max's answer instead, but I'm pretty sure it would work too, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Resources cannot be created by `for_each`'ing a list since there must be a unique key that will become part of the terraform resource name. List indexes cannot be a reliable key since your TF plan will be all messed up if you reorder items in the list.

Maps on the other hand do have unique keys by definition.

You can generate a map from a list though! I found this little trick [here](https://www.sheldonhull.com/blog/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-objects-with-terraforms-for-each-function/#another-way-using-expressions). Note you additionally need to manually compute the unique map key (`${txt_record[0]}=${txt_record[1]}` in the example below).

Your resources with updates in place:

```
module "example_com_dns" {
  ...

  txt_records = [
    ["@",                     "txt-foobar1"],
    ["@",                     "txt-foobar2"],
    ["mail._domainkey.self",  "foobar"],
  ]
}
```

```
resource "digitalocean_record" "this_txt_record" {
  for_each = {for txt_record in var.txt_records: "${txt_record[0]}=${txt_record[1]}" => txt_record}

  domain = var.domain
  type   = "TXT"
  name   = each.value[0]
  value  = each.value[1]
}
```

or slightly more verbose if you prefer:

```
module "example_com_dns" {
  ...

  txt_records = [
    {name: "@", value: "txt-foobar1"},
    {name: "@", value: "txt-foobar2"},
    {name: "mail._domainkey.self", value: "foobar"},
  ]
}
```

```
resource "digitalocean_record" "this_txt_record" {
  for_each = {for txt_record in var.txt_records: "${txt_record.name}=${txt_record.value}" => txt_record}

  domain = var.domain
  type   = "TXT"
  name   = each.value.name
  value  = each.value.value
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I was struggling to reach `each.value.value`. Also, I didn't know about using `:` for assignment in a map like that. Are there any differences with that and using `=`? I couldn't find any reference to it in the HCL spec.

Comment: @Afraz right, both `=` and `:` can be used. Check https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/main/hclsyntax/spec.md#collection-values (`objectelem` definition)